# Apache not going to index.html when accesing the subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've this structure of files

```
/
.htaccess
index.php
/subdirectory
    index.html
```

My .htaccess has this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

On server A apache 2.4 I go to `http://servera/subdirectory/` and it loads the `index.html` file on that directory.

On server B instead, apache 2.4 also, I go to `http://serverb/subdirectory/` and it lodas the index.php at root folder, specified on .htaccess.

Both have `AllowOverride All` and `DirectoryIndex` like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

If on serverB I edit the .htaccess files to be like this:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

then it displays the index.html when accessing the /subdirectory/

What could be the reason? Why is not required the !-d on servera?

Comment: You actually should be using `RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` on both servers so that the rewrite does not write to real directories, so ServerB is functioning correctly.

Comment: I'm not asking which server is functioning correctly, but why is there a difference.